# Save list in Excel with fixed first column text

Tags: python, excel, list, dataframe

At the moment, my code saves a list of folders and subfolders containing files in a txt and in an excel.
I need the first column (1A) in Excel to have the fixed text "Full path", what can I do to accomplish this?

```
import os, sys, shutil
import pandas as pd

ruta = "Path to my Folder"
os.listdir(path=ruta)
miArchivo = open("Path to my txt","w")

def getListOfFiles(ruta):
 listOfFile = os.listdir(ruta)
 allFiles = list()
 for entry in listOfFile:
    fullPath = os.path.join(ruta, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
        allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
    else:
        allFiles.append(fullPath)

 return allFiles

listOfFiles = getListOfFiles(ruta)
df = pd.DataFrame(listOfFiles)
for elem in listOfFiles:
  writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
  df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Bak',index=False)
  miArchivo.write("%s\n" % (elem))
  writer.save()
writer.close()
miArchivo.close()
```

This is the output:
[image]

I need to remove the 0, 1, 2 and use my custom texts!

Answer (score 1):

If you want row 1 to contain header info, you will need to modify the `to_excel` call so that it doesn't overwrite your header. Then, you can use `write` to write text into specific cells:

```
...
df.to_excel(writer, startrow=1, startcol=0,sheet_name='Bak',index=False)
writer.write(0, 0, "Full path")
writer.write("%s\n" % (elem))
miArchivo.write("%s\n" % (elem))
...
```

Where 0,0 refers to the zeroth column and zeroth row, which is cell 1A.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! I get this error: NameError: 'worksheet' is not defined

Comment: Ahh yes sorry I used the wrong variable name, should have been `writer` instead, I edited the answer

Comment: Now the error is: AttributeError: '_XlsxWriter' object has no attribute 'write'